# Why find function not returning all the fields's data properly of the document from MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, azure-pipelines, pymongo

We have written some code in Python using pymongo to do fetch and update queries from MongoDB database. The flow of code is like:

1. Fetching from the database
2. Do some consolidation
3. Update the database

When we are running this code for the first time, it is working fine it is fetching properly, it is doing the right consolidation and also the database is updated properly.

When we are doing update in the database what we are doing, in our document that is returned by the fetch function we are adding one key value pair inside one of the field. Basically that field is the array of different objects. We are adding one key value pair to one of the object.

When again this code runs than the issue is coming, it is not fetching the new key value pair that is added in one of the field's object. Instead of this it is fetching all the data. Even if we add some another field it will also fetch that field properly but it is not fetching the key value pair that we added one of the object in field.

Some important points:

1. Also, there is no syntax error while finding and fetching because when we are running the things locally, all the things are working fine, even it is also fetching the new key value pair that we added. It is misbehaving when it is running in the Pipelines.
2. Second thing, there is no concept of replicas we are using in our databse, so all the time even if we are running the things locally or in pipelines it will fetch from the same database.
3. Also there is no issue of cache. Because even after we added the new field the in the same document it will fetch that changes properly.

```
def get_build(origin, product, version_and_build):
    """Returns the build object from the database that corresponds to version_and_build arg"""
    build_index_collection = origin.streak_db.build_index
    build_index_collection.create_index("sortable_build")
    build_index_collection.create_index("build")

    version_string = (
        f"{version_and_build.major}.{version_and_build.minor}.{version_and_build.update}"
    )
    build_string = f"{version_and_build.phase.letter}{version_and_build.build}"
    find_last_build_query = {
        "product": product.lower(),
        "version": version_string.lower(),
    }

    builds = build_index_collection.find(find_last_build_query).sort(
        "sortable_build", pymongo.DESCENDING
    )
    for build in builds:
        if build["build"] == build_string:
            _logger.debug(
                f"build {build['build']} failing {build['failing_count']} new fails {build['new_fails_count']}"
            )
            return build
```

Comment: Post code if you want people to be able to help-